# Cassandra display of column value

Tags: cassandra, upgrade

I have upgraded Cassandra from v0.6 to v0.7.2 following the instructions in `NEWS.txt`. It seemed to be successful, except that the column value has changed.

For example, in 0.6, there was a column that looked like this:

```
(column=Price, value='2.5')
```

Now, in 0.7.2, the same column has changed to this:

```
(column=Price, value=32392e3939)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What are you using to view the data?

Comment: I use thrift (api version 19.4.0) to access the key space. It can return values. The command is " get <cf> [column_name] ". The returned value is changed as I described in my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLI no longer makes assumptions about the type of data you're viewing, so all outputs are in hex unless the data type is known or you tell the CLI to assume a data type.

See this section of the documentation on [human readable data in the CLI](http://www.datastax.com/dev/tutorials/getting_started_0.7/using_cli#using-human-readable-data) for more details.